# Temporarily disable Hyper-V networking components on host

Tags: networking, hyper-v

I have a Windows 10 PC running Hyper-V. Everything works well.

[I've learned](https://www.altaro.com/hyper-v/the-hyper-v-virtual-switch-explained-part-1/) that when Hyper-V installs, it sort of "takes over" the networking in that PC. Everything starts going through the Hyper-V networking components, even traffic directly from the host to the Internet. This manifests in a network called "Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter" appearing in the adapters list on the host.

But now I need to troubleshoot a wireless connection problem that only happens at a specific site, and in that site only with some of the antennas, and even there, it connects for moments before losing access. I was asked by the company installing the wireless in that building to try a test with Hyper-V "out of the way", which I guess, makes sense. Most people there don't have Hyper-V, and don't have problems. On the other hand, my PC connects just fine in all sorts of places, it only has weird problems here.

The question:

**How can I temporarily disable Hyper-V networking components, short of uninstalling Hyper-V, so I can do a differential diagnosis and determine if Hyper-V is the cause of my problems or not?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hyper-V does this if your virtual switch is shared with the management operating system. You can temporarily remove the Hyper-V virtual switch to remove the Hyper-V virtual ethernet adapter.

Comment: Your answer worked (I was only able to test it today). Thanks. For those unsure how to do it, it's in Hyper-V manager, select your server, then Virtual Switch Manager. Disconnect that network card from all virtual switches, and it will again appear in Windows unrelated to the Hyper-V stuff.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to do it by switching the network switch I had created (not the default one) to "private network", so it wasn't attached to my physical adapter anymore. Seems like when there are no more virtual switches using the physical adapter it releases it. This should be more ideal than removing the virtual switch altogether, especially if you have multiple VMs using it. You can just set it back to external when you need.